# How to change backgroundColor of this UIView In UITableView upon scrolled down

Tags: ios, xcode

As title, any help would be appreciated.

1. I've tried tableView's backgroundColor to clear and backgroundView to nil.
2. It's a grouped TableView
3. I have a headerView populated by UISearchBar

According to the hierarchy, the UIView seemed to be generated upon scrolling down.

[image]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/Bg7fX7V/Screenshot-2019-08-19-at-1-59-48-pm.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Setting a clear background view seemed to do the job. Suspected to be a behaviour added where UISearchBar is used as HeaderView of a TableView.

```
let bgView = UIView()
bgView.backgroundColor = .clear
tableView.backgroundView = bgView
```